# Max sal to print base on manager_id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
id  mgr_id  sal
1   5       5000
2   5       6000
3   6       7000
4   6       8000
```

I expect this output:

```
id  mgr_id  sal MaX_sal
1   5      5000 6000
2   5      6000 6000
3   6      7000 8000
4   6      8000 8000
```

Based on `mgr_id` select max sal and print in front of id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Diogo Rocha . . . Please suggest any answer

Comment: please provide more details about `Max_sal`.  How does it work?

Comment: Shouldn't be 3, 6, 7000, 8000?

Comment: updated the output please check now

Comment: this sal of id and group by base on mgr_id then max(sal) return in front of belonging id.

Comment: @CM2K from the context of the expected output its not max_sal  but max(sal) what is meant there.

Answer (score 0):

Possible would be a subselect inside the select (although a bit slow as all subselects are):

```
select id, mgr_id, sal, (select max(sal) from mytable n2 
where n2.mgr_id = mytable.mgr_id) as max_sal from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

With **SQL Server 2012** simply use this query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.mgr_id, d.sal, MAX(sal) over(partition by mgr_id)
FROM @data d
```

You can use this query with **SQL Server <2012:**

```
SELECT d.id, d.mgr_id, d.sal, m.mx
FROM @data d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT mgr_id, mx = MAX(sal) FROM @data
    GROUP BY mgr_id
) m
ON m.mgr_id = d.mgr_id;
```

Another option with **SQL Server >= 2005:**

```
SELECT d.id, d.mgr_id, d.sal, m.mx
FROM @data d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT mx = MAX(sal) FROM @data m WHERE m.mgr_id = d.mgr_id) m(mx)
```

**Sample data:**

```
Declare @data table([id] int, [mgr_id] int, [sal] int);

INSERT INTO @data([id], [mgr_id], [sal])
VALUES
    (1, 5, 5000),
    (2, 5, 6000),
    (3, 6, 7000),
    (4, 6, 8000)
;
```

Comment: Out of interest (currently can't try it out) the inner join with the group by subselect is that as fast as a subselect (with a where included) inside the select?

Comment: on my VM with a small table, no index, Subselect, Inner Join, cross apply give similar results.

Comment: don't take it for granted though. it will vary with table design, data, indexes...

Answer (score 0):

This would work even in SQL Server 6.5

```
SELECT id, mgr_id, sal, 
    (
        SELECT MAX(sal) 
        FROM employees mgr 
        WHERE mgr.mgr_id = emp.mgr_id
    ) AS max_sal
FROM
   employees emp
```

This works on SQL Server 2005:

```
WITH max_sals AS
(

    SELECT mgr_id, MAX(sal) AS max_sal
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY mgr_id
)
SELECT emp.*, max_sals.max_sal
FROM
    employees emp
    LEFT JOIN max_sals
        ON emp.mgr_id = max_sals.mgr_id
```

and this using partiton:

```
SELECT emp.*, MAX(emp.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY emp.mgr_id) AS max_sal
FROM employees emp
```

Sample data and table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  id int,
  mgr_id int,
  sal int

)

INSERT INTO employees VALUES
(1,5,5000),
(2,5,6000),
(3,6,7000),
(4,6,8000)
```

Comment: Yes!. 6.5 was the first SQL Server version I worked on. Long since

Comment: Same but I hope it's not needed anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a subtable grouping by mrg_id to get the max Sal per mrg_id and then left join it with the principal table on mrg_id -- Try this :

```
declare @table table (id int,mrg_id int,sal decimal(10,0))

insert into @table
select 1,   5,       5000 union all
select 2,   5,       6000 union all
select 3,   6,       7000 union all
select 4,   6,       8000 

/***** change @table with your table name *****/ 
SELECT 
t.id,
t.mrg_id,
t.sal,
t1.max_sal
FROM @table t
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
mrg_id,
MAX(sal) max_sal
FROM @table
group by 
mrg_id) t1
on t.mrg_id=t1.mrg_id
```

Comment: Why are you using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Julien Vavasseur LEFT JOIN doesn't hurt. In some versions of SQL Server INNER JOIN confuses cardinality estimates. Did you downvote this answer?

Comment: @Julien Vavasseur i am using left join because i used the same table in the subtable and its better in performance. there is no reason to downvote the answer!!!

Comment: Sorry the late reply @Amine Zaminex. I just ran tests on 2008 through 2012 with all answers on a sample table, random values, PK on ID w/o or with indexes (mgr_id, sal desc) include(id) or (mgr_id) include(sal, id), with 100, 1000, 10.000 or 100.000 rows and w/o or with where (where mgr_id = X). INNER JOIN always give the best performance and query plan although MAX over is sometimes a bit better. W/o Where LEFT get closer or similar to INNER when there are more rows. With Where, INNER is always better than LEFT no matter the number of rows. LEFT and CTE give the same plan and performance.

Comment: see previous comment @Jesús López

Comment: Ihave seen too many times queries where LEFT OUTER JOIN performs better than INNER JOIN with the same query results, so there is no reason to downvote this answer because this query returns the right results. Not always INNER JOIN perform better, that is not true.

Answer (score -1):

Try Cross Apply,

```
SELECT      id,
            mgr_id,
            sal,
            Max_sal
FROM        #your_table A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Max(SAL) AS Max_sal
             FROM   #your_table B
             WHERE  B.mgr_id = A.mgr_id)cs
```